# Oracle SQL Query to properly position the data based on time intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I have table load_ext which is an external table for the below file structure

| customer | interval_type | data_count | Start_time | interval1 | interval2 | interval3 | ,..interval24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 67891 | 60 | 5 | 06022022040000AM | 0.07 | 0.767 | 0.65 | 0.69 | 0 | 0... |
| 12345 | 60 | 8 | 06022022120000PM | 0.07 | 0.767 | 0.65 | 0.69 | 0.767 | 0.69 | 0 | 0 |

To explain the above columns, All columns are varchar2. Interval type is in minutes, data_count column says the number of intervals to be posted starting from the start_time column, Interval1 is the value for 00:00:00 to 01:00:00 AM and likewise. Target table will have the same structure but the above intervals should be moved to the respective columns. For example, the value of interval1 column in the first row should be moved to column interval4 and the same for all other columns to the respective interval periods.

My target table should have the data like below

| customer | interval_type | data_count | Start_time | interval1 | interval2 | interval3 | interval4 | interval5 | ..interval24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 67891 | 60 | 5 | 06022022040000AM | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.07 | 0.767 | 0.65 | 0.81 | 0 | 0 |
| 12345 | 60 | 8 | 06022022120000PM | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.07 | 0.65 | 0.07 | 0.65 | 0 | 0... |

I am providing the table data with ',' delimiter as the table structure is too big to post in the same format. This has to be done in Oracle only, we are using Oracle 19.

Comment: "For example, the value of interval1 column in the first row should be moved to column interval8 and the same for all other columns to the respective interval periods." Why? Please [edit] your question to explain the logic you are using.

Comment: @MT0, Sorry it should be to Interval4 column not 8. I am editing it.

Comment: That does not explain **WHY** it should be interval4 or interval8? Do you want us to move them all to random intervals? Do you want them in specific intervals, and if so, why those intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for trying to help me, I figured out an alternate and faster way of doing it. Instead of using the load_ext which is an external table, I preferred using the utl_file to read the file directly line by line and writing the same by to new file, in between, I used an existing table that has rows already created for each interval.

My existing for interval periods has start and end time stamp for every 15 mins and its respective period number. So I just considered this period number based on the timestamp from the file for the respective line and generate as many spaces and concatenate to the last column of the file. The last column in the file contains all the intervals but only limited to the number provided in the data_count field of the file.

My steps are like this.

1. Rename and Open the source file in loop
2. Read the one line at a time, retrieve the data field.
3. Based on the timestamp, get the period number from the existing table and add data_count to this.
4. Generate as many spaces as derived in step 3 and concatenate to data field.
5. write this to a new file named as actual source file.

My job is done in a faster way compared to the SQL query.

Thank You Again

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to deal with it. First UNPIVOT the intervals, then index them (COLUMN_NO) and use MODEL clause to shift the values according to DATA_COUNT and finaly PIVOT it back again. Here is the sample with 12 intervals:

```
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            SELECT  '67891'                 "CUSTOMER",
                    '60'                    "INTERVAL_TYPE",
                    '5'                     "DATA_COUNT",
                    '06022022040000AM'      "START_TIME",
                    '0.07'                  "INTERVAL1",
                    '0.767'                 "INTERVAL2",
                    '0.65'                  "INTERVAL3",
                    '0.69'                  "INTERVAL4",
                    '0.62'                  "INTERVAL5",
                    '0.61'                  "INTERVAL6",
                    '0.70'                  "INTERVAL7",
                    '0.68'                  "INTERVAL8",
                    '0.62'                  "INTERVAL9",
                    '0.59'                  "INTERVAL10",
                    '0.69'                  "INTERVAL11",
                    '0.60'                  "INTERVAL12"    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        --
            SELECT  '12345'                 "CUSTOMER",
                    '60'                    "INTERVAL_TYPE",
                    '8'                     "DATA_COUNT",
                    '06022022120000PM'      "START_TIME",
                    '0.07'                  "INTERVAL1",
                    '0.767'                 "INTERVAL2",
                    '0.65'                  "INTERVAL3",
                    '0.69'                  "INTERVAL4",
                    '0.767'                 "INTERVAL5",
                    '0.69'                  "INTERVAL6",
                    '0.70'                  "INTERVAL7",
                    '0.68'                  "INTERVAL8",
                    '0.62'                  "INTERVAL9",
                    '0.59'                  "INTERVAL10",
                    '0.69'                  "INTERVAL11",
                    '0.60'                  "INTERVAL12"    FROM DUAL
        ), 
    datarows AS
        (
            SELECT  CUSTOMER, INTERVAL_TYPE, DATA_COUNT, START_TIME,
                    VALUE_NAME, VALUE_OF
            FROM    tbl
                UNPIVOT (
                            VALUE_OF FOR VALUE_NAME 
                                IN (INTERVAL1, INTERVAL2, INTERVAL3, INTERVAL4, INTERVAL5, INTERVAL6, 
                                    INTERVAL7, INTERVAL8, INTERVAL9, INTERVAL10, INTERVAL11, INTERVAL12)
                        )
        ),
    dataset AS
        (
            SELECT 
                CUSTOMER, INTERVAL_TYPE, DATA_COUNT, START_TIME,
                REPLACE(VALUE_NAME, 'INTERVAL', '') "COLUMN_NO",
                VALUE_NAME,
                VALUE_OF,
                VALUE_OF "ORIG_VALUE"
            FROM 
                datarows
        ),
    combined AS
        (
            SELECT
                CUSTOMER,
                INTERVAL_TYPE,
                DATA_COUNT,
                START_TIME,
                COLUMN_NO,
                VALUE_NAME,
                Nvl(VALUE_OF, '0') "VALUE_OF",
                ORIG_VALUE
            FROM
                dataset
            MODEL
                PARTITION BY (CUSTOMER)
                DIMENSION BY (COLUMN_NO, DATA_COUNT)
                MEASURES (VALUE_OF, VALUE_NAME, INTERVAL_TYPE, START_TIME, ORIG_VALUE)
                    RULES ITERATE(12)
                        (       
                            VALUE_OF[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1, ANY]  = CASE 
                                                              WHEN CV(COLUMN_NO) - To_Number(CV(DATA_COUNT)) + 1 < 0  - To_Number(CV(DATA_COUNT)) - 1 --CV(COLUMN_NO)
                                                              THEN '0' 
                                                          ELSE 
                                                              ORIG_VALUE[To_Char(To_Number(CV(COLUMN_NO)) - To_Number(CV(DATA_COUNT)) + 2), CV(DATA_COUNT)]
                                                          END
                        )
        )
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CUSTOMER,
        INTERVAL_TYPE,
        DATA_COUNT,
        START_TIME, 
        VALUE_NAME,
        VALUE_OF
    FROM 
        combined
    WHERE CUSTOMER = '67891'
)
PIVOT(
        MAX(VALUE_OF)
          FOR VALUE_NAME
            IN ('INTERVAL1', 'INTERVAL2', 'INTERVAL3', 'INTERVAL4', 'INTERVAL5', 'INTERVAL6', 
              'INTERVAL7', 'INTERVAL8', 'INTERVAL9', 'INTERVAL10', 'INTERVAL11', 'INTERVAL12')
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            CUSTOMER,
            INTERVAL_TYPE,
            DATA_COUNT,
            START_TIME, 
            VALUE_NAME,
            VALUE_OF
        FROM 
            combined
        WHERE CUSTOMER = '12345'
    )
    PIVOT(
            MAX(VALUE_OF)
              FOR VALUE_NAME
                IN ('INTERVAL1%' AS INTERV1, 'INTERVAL2', 'INTERVAL3', 'INTERVAL4', 'INTERVAL5', 'INTERVAL6', 
                  'INTERVAL7', 'INTERVAL8', 'INTERVAL9', 'INTERVAL10', 'INTERVAL11', 'INTERVAL12')
        )
--      
--      
--  CUSTOMER INTERVAL_TYPE DATA_COUNT START_TIME       'INTERVAL1' 'INTERVAL2' 'INTERVAL3' 'INTERVAL4' 'INTERVAL5' 'INTERVAL6' 'INTERVAL7' 'INTERVAL8' 'INTERVAL9' 'INTERVAL10' 'INTERVAL11' 'INTERVAL12'
--  -------- ------------- ---------- ---------------- ------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ------------ ------------
--  67891    60            5          06022022040000AM         0           0           0.07        0.767       0.65        0.69        0.62        0.61        0.70         0.68         0.62         
--  12345    60            8          06022022120000PM         0           0           0           0           0           0.07        0.767       0.65        0.69         0.767        0.69
```

Hopefully, you could use it to solve the problem. Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot the columns to rows, add the hours from the start time to the interval and then pivot back to columns:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT customer,
         interval_type
         data_count,
         start_time,
         MOD(
           interval_name + TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(start_time, 'DDMMYYYYHH12MISSAM'), 'HH24'),
           24
         ) AS interval_name,
         value
  FROM   table_name
  UNPIVOT (value FOR interval_name IN (
    interval1  AS 00,
    interval2  AS 01,
    interval3  AS 02,
    interval4  AS 03,
    interval5  AS 04,
    interval6  AS 05,
    interval7  AS 06,
    interval8  AS 07,
    interval9  AS 08,
    interval10 AS 09,
    interval11 AS 10,
    interval12 AS 11,
    interval13 AS 12,
    interval14 AS 13,
    interval15 AS 14,
    interval16 AS 15,
    interval17 AS 16,
    interval18 AS 17,
    interval19 AS 18,
    interval20 AS 19,
    interval21 AS 20,
    interval22 AS 21,
    interval23 AS 22,
    interval24 AS 23
  ))
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(value) FOR interval_name IN (
    00 AS interval24,
    01 AS interval1,
    02 AS interval2,
    03 AS interval3,
    04 AS interval4,
    05 AS interval5,
    06 AS interval6,
    07 AS interval7,
    08 AS interval8,
    09 AS interval9,
    10 AS interval10,
    11 AS interval11,
    12 AS interval12,
    13 AS interval13,
    14 AS interval14,
    15 AS interval15,
    16 AS interval16,
    17 AS interval17,
    18 AS interval18,
    19 AS interval19,
    20 AS interval20,
    21 AS interval21,
    22 AS interval22,
    23 AS interval23
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  customer,
  interval_type,
  data_count,
  Start_time,
  interval1,
  interval2,
  interval3,
  interval4,
  interval5,
  interval6,
  interval7,
  interval8,
  interval9,
  interval10,
  interval11,
  interval12,
  interval13,
  interval14,
  interval15,
  interval16,
  interval17,
  interval18,
  interval19,
  interval20,
  interval21,
  interval22,
  interval23,
  interval24
) AS
SELECT 67891, 60, 5, '06022022040000AM', 0.07, 0.767, 0.65, 0.69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12345, 60, 8, '06022022120000PM', 0.07, 0.767, 0.65, 0.69, 0.767, 0.69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CUSTOMER | DATA_COUNT | START_TIME | INTERVAL24 | INTERVAL1 | INTERVAL2 | INTERVAL3 | INTERVAL4 | INTERVAL5 | INTERVAL6 | INTERVAL7 | INTERVAL8 | INTERVAL9 | INTERVAL10 | INTERVAL11 | INTERVAL12 | INTERVAL13 | INTERVAL14 | INTERVAL15 | INTERVAL16 | INTERVAL17 | INTERVAL18 | INTERVAL19 | INTERVAL20 | INTERVAL21 | INTERVAL22 | INTERVAL23 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 12345 | 60 | 06022022120000PM | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | .07 | .767 | .65 | .69 | .767 | .69 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
> | 67891 | 60 | 06022022040000AM | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | .07 | .767 | .65 | .69 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=315a63845a540af4cc7555887caee721)*

Comment: Apologies, I have an emergency to look after and will check both the solutions once I am back at work. Thanks for your quick responses.